# Dynamically load symbols preview to plugin

Tags: python, pyqgis, symbology, dynamic

I am working on plugin which combines two *.qml files into new one. Now I'm trying to generate something like "list" in plugin interface. What I have done so far is saving repeated in both files keys in list and their symbols previews as svg files in two different directories.

What I want to know is if there is a way to display previews of symbols in my plugin window (in something like list)?

The difficulty is that I don't know how many symbols previews will be in that list - it could be once 3 and another time 20. It must be dynamically loaded then.

Here is a figure how I want it to be (sorry for making it in paint, it's only to understand my idea better):

[image]

Anyone has same problem?

Comment: do you want put a symbol and a checkbox in a QListWidget?Add a icon in each QListWidgetItem. http://pythoncentral.io/pyside-pyqt-tutorial-the-qlistwidget/